# How can i see Google Mirror API at Google APIs console

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-api-console

I followed this article: https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/java
and try to create a Google APIs Console Project.

But in Services tab I don't see Google Mirror API to enable it!

Comment: It is in Developer Preview stage. The API seems not ready for everyone yet. ( I can't find the item in my API list too )

Answer (score 1):

Try again. At the time you asked the question, the Mirror API was behind a whitelist, but that whitelist has since been removed. Now anyone can enable the Mirror API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems its not available to everyone. Follow this thread and it becomes clear.
https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/cwWuUY6xYKW

However, it seems you can try it out on https://developers.google.com/glass/playground.

Comment: The Playground will only work if you have the Mirror API enabled on your project. Without it, it's just a designer.

Answer (score 0):

I just picked up my Glass today and they manually enable the Mirror console once you pick up.  Even after they whitelisted me for the API, it took about 3 hours to be activated on my account.